# Find diff for two datasets with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have two datasets in files with the following data (~500 millinons lines in each file):

```
Dataset1:
a1
a2
a3
a4

Dataset2:
a1
a2
```

I want to find elements in Dataset1 which isn't existing in Dataset2
So, the result should be:

```
Dataset3
a3
a4
```

What is the best way to do this with Hadoop? Any Join-related machanisms, or Pig, or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it easlily using HIVE.
1. [Create a table](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-ddl.html#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable) 
2. [Load data](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-dml.html#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables)
3. Query, simple LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT Dataset1.a LEFT JOIN Dataset1.a=Dataset2.a WHERE Dataset2.a IS NULL
```

Done! GL!

Answer (score 4):

This is easy with Pig using the `COGROUP` operator:

```
dataset1 = LOAD '/path/to/dataset1' USING PigStorage('\n') AS (line:chararray);
dataset2 = LOAD '/path/to/dataset2' USING PigStorage('\n') AS (line:chararray);

grpd = COGROUP dataset1 BY line, dataset2 BY line;
d1_only = FOREACH (FILTER grpd BY IsEmpty(dataset2)) GENERATE FLATTEN(dataset1);
```